# Programmatic way to loop over columns and replace null values with zeros in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, dynamic-sql

I am trying to prepare a large data table in BigQuery for a regression that involves lots of "dummy" (aka categorical) variables.

One of final steps in this process requires me to effectively replace all instances of null values in the table with zeros.

Is there a clean and programmatic way to do this in Big Query? For example, in the table below, I'd ideally like to loop over all the "country_*" fields, and replace with zero in a non hard coded fashion. I have an inkling that this may be a job for dynamic SQL, but I get pretty lost swimming in the documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

TLDR: This is an example of the data structure I'm facing.

| country | country_1 | country_2 | country_3 | other covariates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | - | - |  |
| 2 | - | 1 | - |  |
| 3 | - | - | 1 |  |

This is what I'd like to have

| country | country_1 | country_2 | country_3 | other covariates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |

Simpleton method:

```
select country, 
       ifnull(country_1, 0) as country_1,
       ...
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
create temp function  extract_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as "return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));";
create temp function  extract_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as "return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));";
select * except(json)
from (
  select json, col, val
  from your_table t,
  unnest([struct(replace(to_json_string(t), ':null', ':0') as json)]),
  unnest(extract_keys(json)) col with offset
  join unnest(extract_values(json)) val with offset
  using(offset)
)
pivot (any_value(val) for col in ('country', 'country_1', 'country_2', 'country_3'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mikhail! I tried implementing your code, but received the following message in BigQuery. 

"Function not found: extract_keys"

Do I need to define an auxilary function?

Comment: sorry, missed to paste it. updated answer. try now :o)

Comment: One quick follow up question. Is there a fast way for BigQuery to dynamically populate the pivot line with a full list of all the various columns?

Comment: sure. i have few answers for exact that technique! search for dynamic pivot here on SO. if still a problem, post new question with all relevant details and we will be happy to further help